# Find a FLT that maps the region between $\{|z-1| = 1\}$ and $\{|z|=2\}$ to the region between $Re(z) = -1$ and $Re(z) = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find a Fractional Linear Transformation (if one exists) that maps the region between the circles $\{|z-1| = 1\}$ and $\{|z|=2\}$ to the region between the horizontal lines $\operatorname {Re}(z) = - 1$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z) = 1$.

I have done the following so far:

Step 1: map regions between circles onto a strip:
$$\frac{az + b}{cz +d} = \frac{iz}{z-2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping the region to some strip by sending the intersection point of the two circles to infinity is a good start. An even simpler choice for this operation is
$$
 T(z) = \frac{1}{z-2} \, .
$$
Then, since the two circles intersect the real axis at a right angle and $T$ maps the (extended) real axis onto itself, the images of the two circles are the vertical lines
$$
 \operatorname{Re}(z) = T(0) = -\frac 12
$$
and
$$
 \operatorname{Re}(z) = T(-2) = -\frac 14 \, .
$$
Also, since $T(-1) = -1/3$, the region between the circles is mapped onto the strip between those two vertical lines.

It remains to map this vertical strip to the strip between the lines $\operatorname{Re}(z) = \pm 1$, which can be achieved with an affine map of the form $z \mapsto \alpha z + \beta$.